# Is there a formula/conditional formatting trick for returning/duplicating a cell into a column based on a value in another column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a way to have a cell returned/duplicated into a column (the yellow highlighted column) based on a value that I put in the "Answer" Column?

I am willing to change up my spreadsheet if need be to make this work.

[image: pic]

Comment: Examine the `HLOOKUP` function.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to use the function [Lookup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb).  In your example you'll enter the following into the cell following your first answer (D):

=LOOKUP(F2,$B$1:$E$1,$B2:$E2)

Breaking it down, there are 3 pieces of information this function uses.

1. Your answer.
2. The list of letters that the answers correspond to.
3. The answers.

The dollar signs ($) are placed so that you can 'click and drag' to copy the function into other cells, and it will automatically update to point at the answers in that row.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! :)